# Determinar que un numero es divisible con otro en C

Tags: c

espero que me puedan ayudar con esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    printf("ingrese 2 numeros: \n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    c=a%b;
    if ((b<a) && (c==0)) {
        printf("es divisible\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Si me pueden decir que es lo que esta mal, me ayudaría mucho.
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué número debe ser divisible entre cuál? a entre b? a entre c? b entre c? b entre a?, c entre b? c entre a? etc...?

En caso de ser a entre b, basta con comprobar que b sea diferente a 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

la condicion del `if(b<a) && (c==0)` se podria simplificar de la siguiente manera, si Queremos saber si `a` es Divisible entre `b` quedaria `if(a % b == 0){ //Lo demas }` como sabras, solo hace falta verificar que el modulo(`%`) de `a` y `b` sea igual a `0` es decir su resto sea exacto, te dejo una propuesta de solucion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int a, b;
   printf("Ingrese 2 numeros: \n");
   scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
   if((a % b == 0) && (b!=0))
   {
      printf("%d es Divisible entre %d",a,b);
   }else{
      printf("%d NO es Divisible entre %d",b,a);
   }

   return 0;
   }
```

Cualquier cosa o duda, me escribes, Saludos.

> **Update 1:**
>   Se Agregó la condición `(b!=0)` ya que la división entre `0` no tiene un valor definido. Cambio sugerido por: [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion)

Comment: Para terminar de rizar el rizo no estaría de más comprobar que b es distinto de 0